# Layover-like questions -- on topic or not?

Tags: discussion, scope

Why [my question](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/73450/15281) is closed, while [very similar one](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/69052/15281) is not? What makes the other one so exceptional?

(would be great to get this answer from *CMaster* or *Mark Mayo*, since they marked my question as off-topic)

In addition, there are many other layover-like or sightseeing-like questions around the site which are not only not closed, but also gets a lot of up votes in addition.

Can someone provide a concise explanation, if layover-like question are or are not on-topic for this site? And threat *all* questions of this sort the same?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have just now looked at both questions you cited and the problem became immediately obvious. But I agree that it would be less obvious for someone that had not spent a [tragic] amount of time here.

If you will accept blunt remarks...

Your question is an opinion poll about 'must see'.  For some this would be a bordello and for others it would be the marketplace and still others would insist it would be a shrine.  This is a collection of opinions where each is as valid as the next and if you select one as 'correct' everyone else's feelings will be hurt.

The other question draws an arbitrary circle around the airport with a radius of 10 hours and asks what's inside that circle.

Subtile.  And given the two questions, possibly unfair and absolutely inconsistent. It's great that you came to META to hash it out.

Comment: I have accepted your answer, however I disagree with you on some small point. Question like "what is inside the circle" maybe will not attract as many opinion-based questions as mine, but will most likely attract a lot of not concise, not full-featured answers, because everyone answering will most likely be seeing different interesting things in this "circle". Thus, both questions seems to be off the scope of SE Q&A-like style questions. And certainly both questions rises strong need for a explanation in help, that such questions are off-topic.

Comment: @trejder yes, the review surface is massively uneven.  We have almost DOUBLED the number of voting users in 2016 and so the 'mood' of tolerance/intolerance will shift again.  I suggest waiting until lots of people answer this question so as to see what the current sentiment really is.